# parseJSON unexpected token error

Tags: jquery

Here is my code:

```
$.post( 'request_ajax', $( "#clientDetail" ).serialize(),  "json" )
 .done(function( data ) {
    console.log( data );
    info= $.parseJSON(   data );
  });
```

Error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token  
(anonymous function)
 jquery-2.1.0.js:9109c.fireWith 
jquery-2.1.0.js:9109k 
jquery-2.1.0.js:9109x.support.cors.e.crossDomain.send.t
```

Output:

```
      {"status":"1","clientID":"6","requestID":71}
```

Problem: data is a string type, why it could not be parsed?

Comment: since you are setting the datatype as `json`, jQuery will give you the parsed data in the callback.. so no need to parse it again

Comment: But, I try to access data with data['status'], data.status, or data[0] all of this is unidentified.

Comment: typeof data, which is a string

Comment: so your done callback is getting called?

Comment: yes, is called and return error.

Comment: It works for: info= $.parseJSON( '{"status":"1","clientID":"6"}');           but not: info= $.parseJSON(   data) );

Comment: is there extra whitespace? Try `$.parseJSON($.trim( data) )`